# Send array from async function node js to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to send an js array from my node js backend to my html, but the object in HTML is an Promise Object, how could I send correctly the array?

I'm getting this error =

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

> console.log([object Promise]);

**Backend:**

```
 const path = require('path');
 const fs = require("fs");
 const host = "127.0.0.1";
 const port = 1337;
 const express = require("express");
 const ejs =  require("ejs");


const server = express();
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/js')));//middleware
server.use(express(__dirname)); 
server.set('view engine','html');
server.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

server.get("*", function(request, response){ 
 response.render('index.html', {obj: productArr});
});
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'this.myshopify.com',
  apiKey: 'apikey',
  password: 'pass'
});

async function getJson() {
 return shopify.product.list();
}

let productArr = getJson();
//console.log(productArr);

server.listen(port, host);
console.log('Running at Port 1337');
```

**FrontEnd**

```
<script>
   console.log(<%= obj %>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an async function and await the promise:

```js
server.get("*", async function(request, response){ 
 response.render('index.html', {obj: await productArr});
});
```

More info on [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Also in your `index.html` you need to convert the object to a string and change `<%=` to `<%-` (which doesn't escape the text):

```html
<script>
   console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(obj) %>);
</script>
```

More info on [JSON stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [ejs](https://ejs.co/)